# Checking if two objects are equals, null matching everything

Tags: java, null, equality

Believe me or not, despite the plethora of questions asking about equality and `null`, I could not find an answer to this particular question:

**Is there a standard method (or in a commonly used library) that compares two objects, and return true if they are equals or if one or more is null?**

### Example

I could write this code:

```
a == null || b == null || a.equals(b)
```

But it would be nice to simply encapsulate it in a `EqualsUtils.equalsOrNull(a, b)`.
Easier to read and maintain.

Thing is, there is little point in writing my own if there is a commonly used one already that Jimmy will understand immediately when he gets to maintaining my code.

For this particular project, I can only use standard Java 7, or Apache Commons. Answers using other libraries (such as Guava and the like) are welcome for the sake of future readers, if they do not reference something "too obscure".

Niche answers for `a` and `b` of type `String` are welcome too, as it covers my use case.

Comment: if ``a`` is ``null`` but ``b`` is not ``null``, you want to return ``true``? Does not sound very common to me.

Comment: As your idea is so idiosyncratic, I'd advise you to always write it long-hand.

Comment: I admit it's uncommon. I have records with three IDs (for 3 different systems this application is connected to). The primary ID is key, and therefore mandatory, but the second and third are optional, and may be null. This function would be used to detect data inconsistencies (not matching AND neither is null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is little point in writing my own in there is a commonly used
>   one already

This is not a commonly used pattern, it is illogical.  Write your own if it fits your need.

But for other more conventional patterns use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), or [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/).

Comment: I preferred "idiosyncratic" than "illogical", but true, it's peculiar. I'll accept your answer if no-ones comes up with a solution. (I indeed wrote my own method in the meantime.)